# Switched capacitor ladder is semi-stable but sometimes oscillates

Tags: switching-regulator, oscillation

**[Edited to add a video of what happens on load application]**

I've rebuilt the circuit on perfboard and increased the gate resistors to 50 Ohm as that helped the breadboard version but I'm still having startup and oscillation issues. I think the startup issues are related to the lowest MOSFET being partially on when it tries to start switching because of leakage currents but I'm still stuck on what the cause is and what to do about the oscillation.

[**Original**]
With no load (once it starts up) the converter is stable up to about 75kHz but if I put a 30ohm load on it the gates start to oscillate horribly and I get severe shoot through, to the point the the current limit on the supply kicks in. For some reason this state is persistent even after powering off the circuit and disconnecting the load. I have to leave it powered off for typically 10+ seconds before it stabilizes again. The mosfets are perceptibly warm but barely above body temperature to the touch when it starts oscillating. At lower frequencies it does better and is harder or impossible to make misbehave but I'd like to eventually get 10's of watts through it and the most practical way right now seems to be switching faster.

It is currently built on a breadboard and I know long wires are going to have stray inductance which likely isn't helping things but I'm worried something else is going on and I'd like to better understand why it isn't working before I start soldering things to perfboard.

[image: Schematic]

[Oscillation Video](https://i.imgur.com/FYAprj2.mp4)

Comment: I think there is an error in the schematic with a junction at the left of C2. As well, draw the mosfets vertically so the half h-bridge configuration is obvious.

Comment: Looking at the data sheet for the [tps28225](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps28225.pdf) I note that it has automatic thermal shutdown, Pg15 par 7.3.8. Maybe this is why it takes 10 seconds to recover. I also note, on Pg 20 par 8.2.2.2,  that layout is deemed critical. A breadboard has far too many stray capacitances and inductances for stable operation.

Comment: @Kartman Yep, I put the schematic together quickly for this question. I'll update that when I get a chance. Do you have an example for what you mean by drawing them vertically? My goal is to extend this to 6x input voltage but right now I'm only doing 2x to get something working.

Comment: @PeterJennings I don't think it's the driver chip going into thermal shutdown as it's not even warm to the touch and it's still switching (and making the gates oscillate) which shouldn't happen if it's in shutdown. I'll probably go ahead and solder something on perfboard to get a better layout but I was hoping to have a more concrete idea of what was wrong than "too much stray inductance/capacitance" before I did so.